# Installed .pcf fonts not available

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to install the font from http://font.gohu.eu/ on 12.04.  It recommends the pcf font but when I install it, I do not see it in any applications (gvim, gnome-terminal, gnome-tweak-tool).  I tried the ttf as well but it still didn't work.  I haven't had problems with this font installing before.

Answer (score 2):

How are you attempting to install it? Did you double click the TTF, then "Install Font"? If so, did it seem to install without issue? Can you find the font in any of the folders where fonts are usually placed? (See "[Fonts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts)" on the Ubuntu Wiki). If you can't find the font there, try moving it there manually.

Comment: I double clicked and installed both the pcf and ttf.  There were no errors during the install and the files did appear in ~/.fonts.  I tried doing a fc-cache from the command line and it did parse ~/.fonts but said that no fonts where found there.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [this](http://chrisacheson.net/blog/2009/03/21/how-to-get-profont-working-in-ubuntu/), it should work with other pcf fonts too.

You'll probably just have to open a Text Editor, put in he following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
 <selectfont>
  <acceptfont>
   <pattern>
    <patelt name="family"><string>Gohufont</string></patelt>
   </pattern>
  </acceptfont>
 </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

save it as **.fonts.conf** in your home directory and run `fc-cache -fv` once.

Update: For me, it only worked, when using `fc-cache -fv` with sudo.